Features lost after removingl Z and M dimensions from shapefile
I am trying to find out how many miles of road are in block groups in Washington, DC. I am using this roadway functional classification data from the Open Data DC.
I load the shapefile and run the following code:
## Read roads shapefile
DC_Roads <- read_sf('data/Roadway_Functional_Classification/Roadway_Functional_Classification.shp') 

mapview(DC_Roads)

And get the following error message:
Error: Feature creation failed.
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In CPL_write_ogr(obj, dsn, layer, driver, as.character(dataset_options),  :
  GDAL Error 1: ICreateFeature: Mismatched geometry type
2: In CPL_write_ogr(obj, dsn, layer, driver, as.character(dataset_options),  :
  GDAL Error 6: DeleteLayer() not supported by this dataset.

I have been able to deduce this is likely because of Z and M dimensions in the data. Opening the shapefile in ArcGIS allowed me to see both Z and M dimensions were definitely present.
I tried using DC_Roads <- st_zm(DC_Roads) to resolve the issue but I lose half the roads (see picture). It seems to be all roads that are classified as South in DC (anything south of Capitol Street).
Can anyone help me figure out what's going wrong here and how to fix it?


There are two features in your dataset with empty geometries. Remove them and your code will work:
library(sf)
library(mapview)

# Load sf
DC_Roads <- read_sf('data/Roadway_Functional_Classification/Roadway_Functional_Classification.shp')

# Remove features with empty geometries
DC_Roads <- DC_Roads[!st_is_empty(DC_Roads$geometry), ]

# Convert to xy sf
DC_Roads <- st_zm(DC_Roads)

# Plot
mapview(DC_Roads)



I knew I was overlooking something. Thank you!
